# Randomly match items in Python

Tags: python, random

I was wondering if there was an algorithm I could find or a data structure that I could use that would enable me to efficiently randomly pair two sets of data with each other.

Initially, I searched for an algorithm/data structure that would do this for me, but it was to no avail, most likely because I do not know the exact terms to search for. Currently, I'm using the `randint()` function from the `random` library in python to implement my own type of algorithm, however, I'm worried if there may be issues with it not being random enough.

Comment: Can you show an example of the expected inputs and outputs of the algorithm, especially to show what you mean by "randomly pairing two sets of data with each other"?

Comment: Why don't you just shuffle both data sets and pair them off?

Comment: Sounds like you want o split training/test data... if that's the case you may want to checkout this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information you have provided in the question, my approaches would be as follows:

**Approach 1:**

Lets say you have 2 datasets `A` and `B` and an indexing operator `[]`, you could use `randint` to generate 2 random numbers `a` and `b` and pair `A[a]` with `B[b]`. Here the advantage is you can bootstrap as many times you want to generate a dataset as big as you want.

**Approach 2:**

As @Mark Meyer suggested in the comments, shuffle the 2 datasets separately, and then pair each data point.